# Point to new instance of class outside method scope without messing with unsafe code

Tags: c#, oop, pointers

```cs
public void Get(IMqMessageWrapper mqMessageWrapper)
{
     var realMqMessage= new MQMessage();
     mqMessageWrapper= new MqMessageWrapper(realMqMessage);
}
```

```
public interface IMqMessageWrapper 
{
     Encoding Encoding { get; set; } 
     int BackoutCount {get;} // Is readonly
}
```

How to accomplish updating the `mqMessageWrapper` inside the method and still be able to use the updated `mqMessageWrapper` outside the scope of this method without messing with `unsafe`?

I want to be able to use mqMessageWrapper outside the scope of the Get method without having to use a return type (this has to do with rebuilding an existing library and keep things as close to the old implementation as possible).

I know this should be simple but I cannot find the right terms to search for an solution.

EDIT: Some more context:

I am writing a wrapper library for the IBM MQ C# library to make things somewhat easier. The people at IBM had chosen to not return values but to update the object which is passed to the method.

To not have to rewrite things completely I am trying to keep the wrapper classes methods to have mostly the same signatures as the original.

I understand that what I am suggesting is unconventional. And if it is not possible that is also an answer. Refactoring the architecture is not something I want to do immediately but if there is no other viable option that is what I need to do.

The method I am trying to wrap is being used in this example from IBM : https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=programs-example-c-code-fragment-use-net

```cs
// First define an IBM MQ message buffer to receive the message
      MQMessage retrievedMessage =new MQMessage();
      retrievedMessage.MessageId =hello_world.MessageId;

      // Set the get message options
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo =new MQGetMessageOptions(); //accept the defaults
                                                          //same as MQGMO_DEFAULT

      // Get the message off the queue
      system_default_local_queue.Get(retrievedMessage,gmo);

      // Prove we have the message by displaying the UTF message text
      String msgText = retrievedMessage.ReadUTF();
      Console.WriteLine("The message is: {0}", msgText);
```

Comment: It *is* simple - you return a value. That's how you get values out of methods in the most conventional way. There are various *odd* ways you can get values out of methods, such as out parameters, or regular parameters as mutable wrappers - but we only have the vaguest of explanations of why you don't want to do things the most straightforward way, so there's no point in suggesting those odd ways in any level of detail, as any of them could easily be shot down by the unknown requriements.

Comment: @JonSkeet that is the problem. I want to have to method signature to be the same like the original code but then with interfaced classes. Sometimes I just want to learn how to do things and in the process learn something about OO 'internals'. I know it might not be the best way to do things. The rebuild is a currently just a hobby project to learn from how the internals of the original library work. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I changed the example a little bit.

Comment: "Messing" with unsafe won't help you here really. You can change the argument to `ref MyClass result` but that is also a change in signature.

Comment: The explanation still doesn't have enough detail to help us. Basically, you need to modify the object that the original parameter refers to, rather than changing the value of the parameter to refer to a different object.

Comment: Your question seems unclear or contradictory (do you want `result` or `niceResult`?) but you can save `niceResult` or `result` in a variable in an enclosing scope that will allow access.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are right about that. I might want to add some internal setters to allow writing read-only properties inside the library and change the value of these properties instead of trying to change the reference to the complete object. I am also not to fond of the approach the authors have taken in the original library.

Comment: The weird thing is, it seems that the original library uses the `MQMessage` to set some parameters for getting the same instance back using these parameters. That might also be bad design. See: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=programs-example-c-code-fragment-use-net how the original library does get messages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "MyClass" and "someOtherClass" are compatible types, the **cast** syntax looks like this:

```
public void Get(MyClass result)
{
     result = (MyClass)getSomeOtherClass();
}
```

But I'd also change this to return a value:

```
public MyClass Get()
{
     return (MyClass)getSomeOtherClass();
}
```

However, if the "someOtherClass" and "MyClass" type are *not* compatible, there is nothing you can do to make this happen.

So what does "compatible" mean? In this case, `MyClass` must inherit from `someOtherClass` (or vice versa).

Comment: I think the OPs main problem is that he wants to update the `result` argument. Your first suggestion won't work (even if the types match), as result is apparently a reference type.

Comment: @PMF that is right. I cannot shallow copy the object either because there are some read-only properties. But I am really tired now, might be that I just am not thinking straight.